# How to visit the US from Canada as a Polish tourist?

Tags: usa, canada, borders, polish-citizens

I am planning on going to Canada as a tourist, I don't need a visa to go there, but I would love to visit USA as well since I'm there (for which I do need a visa).

How can I get a visa for USA this way? I know they require specific information about flight day, in which hotel I will stay etc. but I don't have such info as I would enter from Canada and I would be traveling around.

Also, will I be able to re enter to Canada once I go to the US? Will I be able to go back a second time to US if I re enter Canada?

EDIT: Polish citizen, living in Italy.

EDIT 2:I will add some more information that might influence the decision of letting me in the country. I don't have a job as I am taking a sort of gap year to travel, I have enough money to travel for a few months, and I have a gold Visa credit card

Comment: What's your nationality? That'll make a big difference to the rules that apply

Comment: It'll depend entirely on your nationality - can you clarify that for us?

Comment: I'm of Polish nationality (Poland has a big turn down rate in visas) but I live in Italy, so I'm hoping they'll consider this, I'm currently taking a gap year between jobs for traveling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a Polish citizen you don't need a [visa prior to arrival](http://www.canadainternational.gc.ca/poland-pologne/visas/faq_citizens_poland-citoyens_polonais.aspx?lang=eng) in Canada if you have a biometric passport, however, you do need one to enter the United States you do need to have a visa as you're **NOT** eligible to enter under [Visa Waiver Program](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit/visa-waiver-program.html).  Which means the following:

1. You can enter Canada as many times as you want as long as you don't exceed maximum allowed stay, which is 6 months or duration determined by the immigration officer.
2. In order to enter US multiple times you will need a multi-entry visa because unless you have one you will only be allowed in the US once and if you leave you will need another visa.
3. In order to obtain the visa you will need to apply for it at a US embassy where you live or in Poland.  There is a [list of required information](http://poland.usembassy.gov/visas/nonimmigrant-visas/required-documents.html) available from the US embassy.

Comment: 1. If I exceed the 6 month period (or whatever the officer gives me) while I'm in the US, will I be able to enter in Canada again or is there a time period I have to wait before I am allowed to enter another time?

2. A multi entry visa is something I have to ask for (different from the normal tourist visa) or it's the same tourist visa and the factor that it's single or multi entry is determined by the US immigration officer?

Comment: 1. The best I can figure the duration resets if you leave Canada so if you're in the US you're not in your 6 months 2. Multi-entry visa is the number of entries you are allowed into the country.  Visa type is B the number of entries doesn't change the type of the visa.

Comment: While there are not hard-and-fast rules like the US, I believe if you stayed in Canada for six months, then went to the US and came back a week later you might have difficulty in persuading the immigration official that you were truly visiting as a tourist.

Comment: FYI Poland was added to the US Visa Waiver Program last month.